# SQLAlchemy + Postgres (print created types, e.g. enum types)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to be able to get info about what types will be created during SQLAlchemy's create_all(). Yes, they can be printed if I set up echo-ing of generated SQL, but how can i print it without actually hitting database? For example, I have a model:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    indexed_field = Column(String(50))
    enum_field = Column(Enum(MyEnum))

    __table_args__ = (
        Index("my_ix", indexed_field),
    )
```

where MyEnum is:

```
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    A = 0
    B = 1
```

I can get `CREATE TABLE` statement and all `CREATE INDEX` statements like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable, CreateIndex

print(str(CreateTable(MyModel.__table__).compile(postgres_engine)))
for idx in MyModel.__table__.indexes:
    print(str(CreateIndex(idx)).compile(postgres_engine))
```

Result will be something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE my_model (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    indexed_field VARCHAR(50), 
    enum_field myenum, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
CREATE INDEX my_ix ON my_model (indexed_field)
```

Notice the line `enum_field myenum`. How can I get generated SQL for `CREATE TYPE myenum...` statement?

Answer (score -2):

I've found the answer!

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base import PGInspector
PGInspector(postgres_engine).get_enums()
```

It returns a list of all created enums, which IMO is even better than raw sql, [documentation is here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.PGInspector.get_enums).